# How to submit assumptions defined in master kernel to subkernels

Tags: parallelization, assumptions

Consider an example:

```
$Assumptions = m > 0 && m \[Element] Integers;
ParallelDo[Print[{$Assumptions, Simplify[Sin[2*Pi*m]]}], {ik, 1, 2}, DistributedContexts -> All]
```

I expect it to produce:

```
{m > 0 && m \[Element] Integers,0}
```

But instead of it, Wolfram Mathematica gives:

```
{True,Sin[2 Notebook$$44$996424`m \[Pi]]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Assumptions` cannot be distributed because it is in the `` System` `` context and because it is a symbol with special behaviour.

The correct way to handle this is to set it explicitly on all subkernels.

```
ParallelEvaluate[$Assumptions = m > 0 && m \[Element] Integers]
```